# Postgresql method for finding the slope of a line and forcing through origin

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-8.4

I have a temporary table with 2 numeric columns, Y and X.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE findslope(y numeric,x numeric);
```

Which I then populate with the desired X and Y for the line I'm trying to fit a least squares best fit line which I am currently using the following:

```
SELECT REGR_SLOPE(y, x) slope FROM findslope into slope_variable;
```

This works well, but is it possible to force the line through a point or to set the intercept? Specifically I'd like the line to go through the origin: 0,0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the working code:

```
SELECT 
  sum(y*x) / sum(x*x) as slope
FROM findslope INTO slope_variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while since I had to get this sort of math right, so verify this on your own. I'd start with [Simple linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) on wiki.

I think will do it:

```
SELECT regr_sxy(y,x)/regr_sxy(x,x) AS slope FROM findslope INTO slope_variable;
```